# Google fonts not working..sometimes

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, google-font-api

Im working on Wordpress website.
I got problem with Google fonts.

Im using this code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

But sometimes font is not working and its replaced by some serif font which is not in CSS as fallback.
It only happens on customers PC Chrome browser. :)

Thanks
M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try with decoded href, just like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,300,600,400&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've deregistred default Wordpress Open Sans css and added your code. Hope it works.